# How to write JSON Object data to a csv file?

Tags: c#, json, csv

I am trying to export the JSON data to a CSV file. I have created a function  WriteReportToCSV() to do this job. When I try to run my program, my code is not reading the function. Am I missing something in my code?

TestApp.cs:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    class TestApp
    {
        public List<report> Reports { get; set; }
        public List<worklog> worklogs { get; set; }
        public List<answer> answers { get; set; }

        public void HarvestRaken()
        {
            var rc = GetReports();

            if (rc == null) return;

            rc.WriteReportToCSV(@"C:\Projects\TestApp\Report_Data.csv");

        }

        public string token = "1abcdef3-k89x-3w574-3589-2957c29ki7m1";

        public reportcontainer GetReports()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Reading Reports");

            reportcontainer result = null;

            try
            {
                string url = "https://app.ticketappapp.com/api/v2/reports/?startDate=2017-06-07&endDate=2017-07-07&maxResults=10000&filters=project.id:279658&filters=project.id:279654&filters=project.id:279652";

                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream responstream = response.GetResponseStream())

                    {
                        string sr = new StreamReader(responstream).ReadToEnd();

                        reportcontainer rc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<reportcontainer>(sr);
                    }
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return result;
        }
```

Project.cs:

```
namespace TestApp
{

    public class reportcontainer
    {
        public List<report> reports { get; set; }
        public string totalHits { get; set; }

        public void WriteReportToCSV(string Filepath)
        {

            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Filepath))
            {

                foreach (report rep in this.reports)

                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Reading Reports:");
                    sw.WriteLine(" Reading:" + "," + rep.id + "," + rep.status + "," + rep.completed + "," + rep.date);

                }

                foreach (worklog wl in this.reports.SelectMany(r => r.worklogs))

                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Reading Worklogs:");
                    sw.WriteLine(" Reading:" + "," + wl.id + "," + wl.subcontractor + "," + wl.hours + "," + wl.workerCount + "," + wl.workdesc);

                }

                foreach (answer ans in this.reports.SelectMany(r => r.answers))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Reading Survey:");
                    sw.WriteLine(" Reading:" + "," + ans.id + "," + ans.question + "," + ans.questionid + "," + ans.FormattedAnswer + "," + ans.desc);

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `When I try to run my program, my code is not reading the function. `? Do you mean you forgot to call `HarvestRaken`? Or something else?

Comment: @mjwills. When I hit Run, it starts to begin harvesting but then it returns (rc == null)  and dose not writeReporttoCSV(). My problem is i am unable to write data to CSV. Not understanding what am I missing in my code.

Comment: @mjwills.I am successfully able to deserializeobject<reportcontainer>(sr)  with no exceptions. what do you mean by,  you have just forgotten to assign to the result variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reportcontainer rc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<reportcontainer>(sr);
```

should be changed to:

```
result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<reportcontainer>(sr);
```

Because you never assign a value to `result`, it is **always** null.

Thus `WriteReportToCSV` is never called.